# String compare not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to compare post titles in wordpress to avoid creating a post with a title that already exists.

```
foreach ($postnamearray as $value) 
{
    if($value === $titelzor)
    {
        echo' '.$value.' === '.$titelzor.' ';
    }
    else
    {
        echo' '.$value.' != '.$titelzor.' <br /> ';
    }
}
```

However, it's not working! When a match is supposed to be found, it comes back as (sorry for dutch text):

```
zovty, bedankt! != zovty, bedankt!
```

But it's supposed to come back as

```
zovty, bedankt! === zovty, bedankt!
```

So the script doesn't seem to detect it as having found a match. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Is there maybe whitespace following one of the strings you compare?

Comment: What really baffles me is that it comes back with four equal signs. Your code has only three. Besides that I agree with Joey.

Comment: @Joey Yep that was it. trim() fixed it. @Leif That was a typo ^^ Fixed it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I guess one of the strings may contain trailing whitespace or newline characters, so try this:

```
if (trim($value) == trim($titelzor)) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you should use multibyte comparison. You can use the Collator object or use iconv or mb_convert_encoding functions to convert the string and after that, you can make equal operation on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using strcmp:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

It's probably an encoding issue.