# Comparing two text variables not working

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, comparison, string-comparison

I have this code:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $ctitle = wp_title('',0);
    $sql = ("SELECT * FROM dbname WHERE naslov LIKE 'Police'");
    $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    foreach ($result as $results) {                            
        $odgovor = $results->naslov; 
    }  
    echo $ctitle;
    echo $odgovor;                                        
    if ( $ctitle === $odgovor ) {
        echo "yes";
    }
    else {
        echo "no";
    }                  

?>
```

And the output is: "PolicePoliceno" - on posts with title "Police" and "Some titlePoliceno" on any other post.
I'm printing variables just for testing...
Goal would be to have answer yes when variables are the same. What am I missing?
Tried with strcmp with similar results

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see you are declaring `$wpdb` there. Are you on Wordpress? If so, I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6439279/string-compare-not-working) that has the same problem with you.

What makes the comparation doesn't work, because there's a whitespace or newline characters on one of two variables (see the accepted answer on that post).

Here is the solution, by trimming both strings:

```php
if (trim($ctitle) === trim($odgovor)) ...
```

Comment: @rizki-parama, if you are going to point to another question, you should use a comment, not an answer. :)

Comment: @yivi I'm sorry, but you see that I don't have enough reputation to comment right? So what should I do?

Comment: Wait until you get the rep. Or try to write meaningful answers. You won't get it by writing bad answers, though.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. And welcome to SO!

Comment: This answer eventually solved it.  Although wp_title function doesn't have whitespace when printed, I was unable to use it even in SQL query without trim, so Thnx Rizki Pratama :)